# How to play these chords on a piano

Tags: piano, technique, practice, fingering, physical-limitations

I want to know how to play the piano notes on the picture and if I just got really small hands.

I play the first two accords with my thumb pressing two keys simultaneously. Is this the correct way or do I just have small hands?

And for the second part, can anyone really hold the upper A while pressing the other three notes? The lower A seems for me quite impossible. 
[image: Notes]

Comment: I can just about execute the second bar with the right hand (left would be much easier), and I have an above-average span. If there is no mitigating factor (e.g. possible use of sustain pedal) than that's just plain bad writing for the right hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing notes next to each other on piano is fine with one finger, and especially one thumb. Slight problem here is the notes are supposed to be arpeggiated, and that's difficult to execute when thumb plays the two as they'll sound out simultaneously. But better that way with the top G slightly later.

The second bar calls out for use of a sostenuto pedal, which will hold the A. A sustain pedal won't work well, as the chord underneath has to be staccato - impossible when the right pedal is already held down.